# transform a pandas dataframe based on the structure given by a python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table in a pandas dataframe:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>AquaticSettingName</th>
      <th>Definition</th>
      <th>d_level_id</th>
      <th>Concat_Code</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>Marine</td>
      <td>The Marine System is defined by salinity, which is typically about 35, although salinity can mea...</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>M</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Estuarine</td>
      <td>The Estuarine System is defined by salinity and geomorphology. This System includes tidally infl...</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>Lacustrine</td>
      <td>The CMECS Lacustrine System includes (a) all deepwater areas of the Great Lakes and (b) shorelin...</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>L</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>Marine Nearshore</td>
      <td>The Marine Nearshore Subsystem extends from the landward limit of the Marine System to the 30 me...</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>M.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>Marine Offshore</td>
      <td>The Marine Offshore Subsystem extends from the 30 meter depth contour to the continental shelf b...</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>M.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>Marine Oceanic</td>
      <td>The Marine Oceanic Subsystem represents the open ocean, extending from the continental shelf bre...</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>M.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>6</th>
      <td>Estuarine Coastal</td>
      <td>The Estuarine Coastal Subsystem extends from the supratidal zone at the land margin up to the 4 ...</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>E.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>7</th>
      <td>Estuarine Open Water</td>
      <td>The Estuarine Open Water Subsystem includes all waters of the Estuarine System with a total dept...</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>E.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>8</th>
      <td>Estuarine Tidal Riverine Coastal</td>
      <td>The Estuarine Tidal Riverine Coastal Subsystem includes the most upstream region of the estuary,...</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>E.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>9</th>
      <td>Estuarine Tidal Riverine Open Water</td>
      <td>The Estuarine Tidal Riverine Open Water Subsystem includes tidal freshwater areas with a salinit...</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>E.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>10</th>
      <td>Lacustrine Limnetic</td>
      <td>The Limnetic Subsystem includes all deepwater habitats within the Lacustrine System. "Deepwater ...</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>L.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>11</th>
      <td>Lacustrine Littoral</td>
      <td>The Littoral Subsystem includes shallow habitats in the Lacustrine System. The shoreward boundar...</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>L.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>12</th>
      <td>Marine Nearshore Subtidal</td>
      <td>The substrate is generally continuously submerged in this zone and includes those areas below MLLW.</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>M.1.a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>13</th>
      <td>Marine Nearshore Intertidal</td>
      <td>The substrate is regularly and periodically exposed and flooded by tidal action. This zone exten...</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>M.1.b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>14</th>
      <td>Marine Nearshore Supratidal</td>
      <td>This zone includes areas above MHHW that are affected by wave splash and overwash but does not i...</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>M.1.c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>15</th>
      <td>Marine Offshore Subtidal</td>
      <td>The substrate is subtidal and continuously submerged in this zone and includes those areas below...</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>M.2.a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>16</th>
      <td>Marine Oceanic Subtidal</td>
      <td>The substrate is subtidal and continuously submerged in this zone.</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>M.3.a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>17</th>
      <td>Estuarine Coastal Subtidal</td>
      <td>The substrate is generally continuously submerged in this zone and includes those areas below MLLW.</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>E.1.a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>18</th>
      <td>Estuarine Coastal Intertidal</td>
      <td>The substrate in this zone is regularly and periodically exposed and flooded by tides. This zone...</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>E.1.b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>19</th>
      <td>Estuarine Coastal Supratidal</td>
      <td>This zone includes areas above MHHW; areas in this zone are affected by wave splash and overwash...</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>E.1.c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>20</th>
      <td>Estuarine Open Water Subtidal</td>
      <td>The substrate is generally continuously submerged in this zone and includes those areas below MLLW.</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>E.2.a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>21</th>
      <td>Estuarine Tidal Riverine Coastal Subtidal</td>
      <td>The substrate is generally continuously submerged in this zone and includes those areas below MLLW.</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>E.3.a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>22</th>
      <td>Estuarine Tidal Riverine Coastal Intertidal</td>
      <td>The substrate in this zone is regularly and periodically exposed and flooded by tides. This zone...</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>E.3.b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>23</th>
      <td>Estuarine Tidal Riverine Open Water Subtidal</td>
      <td>The substrate is generally continuously submerged in this zone and includes those areas below MLLW.</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>E.4.a</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to use the last column to reformat this table in the form:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>System</th>
    <th>SubSystem</th>
    <th>Tidal Zone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Marine</td>
    <td>Marine Nearshore</td>
    <td>Marine Nearshore Subtidal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>Marine Nearshore Intertidal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>Marine Nearshore Supratidal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Estuarine</td>
    <td>Estuarine Coastal</td>
    <td>Estuarine Coastal Subtidal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>Estuarine Coastal Intertidal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>Estuarine Coastal Supratidal</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>Estuarine Open Water</td>
    <td>Estuarine Open Water Subtidal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>Estuarine Tidal Riverine Coastal</td>
    <td>Estuarine Tidal Riverine Coastal Subtidal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>Estuarine Tidal Riverine Coastal Intertidal</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>Estuarine Tidal Riverine Open Water</td>
    <td>Estuarine Tidal Riverine Open Water Subtidal</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lacustrine</td>
    <td>Lacustrine Littoral</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>Lacustrine Limnetic</td>
    <td>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The desired output can be generated using the information included in the  Concat_Code column.

My approach is to use `Split` and `Groupby` as described in [this notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/epifanio/e82443b79c24ceb2d59ba49cad9a62d4) (note: in that notebook I'm using an hackish solution to an issue I had with `groupby` I posted it in a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195515/pandas-groupby-operation-with-missing-data)

from that approach, I derive a new dictionary that looks like:

```
{'E': {'1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
       '2': ['a'], 
       '3': ['a', 'b'], 
       '4': ['a']},
 'L': {'1': ['x'], 
       '2': ['x']},
 'M': {'1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
       '2': ['a'], 
       '3': ['a']}}
```

And I use the dictionary above to construct my pandas dataframe where the first key refers to the first group the second key to the second group and so on ... in a nested for loop I `recreate` the `Concat_Column` which I use to extract the record from the first table. the `row counter` gets an increment every first level group.:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['System', 'Sub System', 'Tidal Zone'])

row=0

for i in k.keys():
    df1.set_value(row, 'System', df[df['Concat_Code']==i].AquaticSettingName.values[0])
    for j in k[i]:
        df1.set_value(row, 'Sub System', df[df['Concat_Code']==i+'.'+str(j)].AquaticSettingName.values[0])
        for v in k[i][j]:
            try:
                df1.set_value(row, 'Tidal Zone', df[df['Concat_Code']==i+'.'+str(j)+'.'+str(v)].AquaticSettingName.values[0])
            except:
                df1.set_value(row, 'Tidal Zone', '')
            row=row+1

import numpy as np
df1 = df1.replace(np.nan,' ', regex=True)
```

which return the desidered output.

Is there a better, simplest, more robust way to achieve the same result?